# How do I return a status code, status description and text together in MVC3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

From my MVC3 controller action I want to return HTTP 403, set "status description" to some specific string and also return that string in the result content so that it is visible in the browser.

I can return `ContentResult` to specify content, but not a status code (such as 403) and not a status description. I can use `HttpStatusCodeResult` to specify a status code and status description but not the result content.

How do I craft an action result that contains all three?

Comment: why not use custom Json( {code: descr :}) call ?

Comment: @Tigran: IMO for this simple purpose that would be an overkill.

Comment: as much as I'm aware of, it's not possible, so you need create esplicit composed object. In that case, imo, the most simple solution is is custom Json object. But I'm not ASP.NET expert, may there is a more simple solution for this.

Answer (score 19):

Commonly you would see this done by setting the response code then returning a regular ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Foo() 
{ 
    Response.StatusCode = 403;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Some custom message";

    return View(); // or Content(), Json(), etc
}
```

If you really need this to be an ActionResult, you create your own.

Example:

```
public class HttpStatusContentResult : ActionResult
{
    private string _content;
    private HttpStatusCode _statusCode;
    private string _statusDescription;

    public HttpStatusContentResult(string content, 
                                   HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                   string statusDescription = null)
    {
        _content = content;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
        _statusDescription = statusDescription;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int) _statusCode;
        if (_statusDescription != null)
        {
            response.StatusDescription = _statusDescription;
        }

        if (_content != null)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(_content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `_statusDescription` is null, you could assign it a value of `HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription( response.StatusCode )`, which under the hood is a very fast lookup in `string[][] s_HTTPStatusDescriptions` like `s_HTTPStatusDescriptions[StatusCode / 100][StatusCode % 100]`.  The retrieved value is always a short description of the status code such as 'OK' or 'Forbidden', or an empty string if no matching description is found.

Comment: I tried this solution and it work fine when I run it on IIS express but when I run it on my prod it doesn't work. What it heppening is that from my ajax request, I am expecting the _content value to be mapped to responseText however on prod server IIS also it maps to statusText, refer to this https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26457716/Response-write-not-working-when-deployed-to-IIS-Works-locally.html who also had the same issue

Comment: Just a heads up for now days and http2. Http2 does not support status descriptions. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4 says "HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase
   that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line."

Answer (score 11):

If this is not too dirty

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("Some specific string");
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "another specific string");
```

Comment: or similarly, `Response.StatusCode = 403; Response.StatusDescription="foo"; return Content("bad request mate");`

Comment: Don't forget to clear the response first if you're messing with it ahead of the code: `Response.Clear();`

Answer (score -1):

I went crazy trying to get this code to work before I realized it was the GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(...) that was the problem.  Here's the version I got working:

```
public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
   ...
   // Other code
   ...

   public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      return base
         .ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken)
         .ContinueWith(t =>
         {
            t.Result.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
            {
               NoStore = true,
               NoCache = true,
               MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0),
               MustRevalidate = true
            };
            t.Result.Headers.Pragma.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("no-cache"));
            t.Result.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Parse("01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT");

            return t.Result;
         }, cancellationToken);
   }
}
```

Comment: ApiController isn't in MVC3, it's in Web API which wasn't merged with MVC till .NET Core